# Twitter Bootstrap - making height of html, body and container 100% adds a vertical scrollbar, even with overflow: auto;

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, scrollbar

EDIT: Fiddle does not seem to be loading Twitter Bootstrap properly so I suggest you copy paste my HTML and CSS code into a blank .html file on your desktop and troubleshoot with that file. Please remember to properly include Twitter Bootstrap 3 (the CDN is in my HTML code below) because the issue only appears when Bootstrap is included.

Here is my fiddle / code: http://jsfiddle.net/maLog1sm/

And here is the code which is in the fiddle:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<div class="container-fluid headerRow">
    <div class="row headerRow">
        <div class="col-md-12 navContainer">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked custom-nav-pills">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>  Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-10 bodyColumn">

                <div class="footer"><p>Footer</p></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.bodyColumn {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.headerRow {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
}
```

It uses bootstrap 3. I'm wondering why the vertical scroll bar is there, and how I can remove it (on fiddle, the scrollbar appears whether or not the browser window is shrunk, but on my actual website, it only appears when the window is shrunk. By shrunk, I mean when I make the width of the browser window smaller than it's maximized width).

Comment: i think it's problem with class bodyColumn, Is it ok if you make height:auto for that class?

Comment: You dont need to mention 100% height for most of the classes. Also I dont see any significance of `position: absolute` for .footer class.

Comment: @PralhadNarsinhSonar position:absolute is to help footer to remain always at the bottom of page, no matter how long the content goes on page.

Answer (score 3):

Problem with your code is you that you are giving height 100% to HTML and BODY, it's fine no issue. Also you have gave same height:100% to the 2 classes(two div) inside it, now HTML can not give 100% to both the inner div. You can mention height:auto to the class which will adjust height as per the content available.

Here Try replacing height:100% by height:auto; for class .bodyColumn, it will solve your Issue

**CSS** : Updated

```
.bodyColumn {
    position:absolute !important;
    bottom:0%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.headerRow {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
    display:block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j2yvpp7x/2/) : **Updated**

**Explanation:** Here the first div headerRow takes the whole height(100% height) of page, now for the div bodyColumn is after the above one so it is too given height 100%, so it is forced to do so but its margin:0 starts from where the content ends(here is your navContainer div)

Comment: This did work in the fiddle. However, for some reason, in my actual index.html file on my desktop, when I copy paste this code and open up the file, the footer does not appear at the bottom of the webpage. Any idea why? AndrewLyndem's answer solved the issue and the footer does appear at the bottom of the webpage.

Comment: this is interesting. In your actual .html file (not on fiddle), can you add bootstrap? Basically, just add <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/ css/bootstrap.min.css"> (Removing the white space before the word "css") in the <head></head> section. Does the word "Footer" appear for you at the bottom of the webpage even with Bootstrap?

Comment: on my original post, I mentioned "on fiddle, the scrollbar appears whether or not the browser window is shrunk, but on my actual website, it only appears when the window is shrunk. By shrunk, I mean when I make the width of the browser window smaller than it's maximized width." Can you shrink your browser window (so that it is, say less than 767px) and see if the footer is still visible?

Comment: You didn't load your bootstrap properly (due to my mistake, so I apologize). Load this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4 /css/bootstrap.min.css"> but remove the white space between 3.3.4 and /css/ (you'll know that bootstrap is loaded correctly when icons appear in your HTML list instead of bullets). When Bootstrap is properly loaded, it does not say "Footer" at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: right, but in your screenshots you just posted, the word "Footer" doesn't appear, right? I can't see the word "Footer". I was hoping for there to be a way to remove the scrollbar but still have the word "Footer" appear at the bottom of the page. You get what I'm saying?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the classes and styles defined in html.

In the above case, you are having headerRow class to parent and one of its child. And another child is having bodyColumn class. Both elements having style of height as 100% tries to take the 100% of parent's height and being overflow as auto, the parent will scroll in case of overflow.

I have tried working in your fiddle and removing headerRow from child element fixes your issue.

Comment: Fiddle does not load Twitter Bootstrap 3 properly. Please try copy pasting my HTML and CSS code which I posted on my SO post into a blank .html file and troubleshoot it from there. Your solution worked in Fiddle (because it didn't load Bootstrap properly) but it does not work when Bootstrap is loaded properly (you'll know Bootstrap is loaded properly when the HTML lists have icons beside them instead of bullets).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `height:100%` property in `bodyColumn` and `headerRow` to `min-height:100%` like this:

```
.bodyColumn {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.headerRow {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Leave your body height as `height:100%` though. Don't change the parent height to min-height.**

Comment: it did not work for my html file on my desktop (which has bootstrap properly loaded). Fiddle does not seem to load Bootstrap properly so let's ignore what happens in Fiddle for me (If it loaded bootstrap properly, then the icons would actual appear). For testing purposes, if you create a .html file on your desktop and copy paste the code I posted here on SO (with the Twitter Bootstrap CDN) then the scrollbar still appears when the screen is shrunk.